# How to extract some fields of json array in Big Query

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have a use case where in I want to select few fields present in json array. I'm able to extract single field from the array but multiple field results in an issue. I want to extract **upc and qty** from sample sales data..

```
{ "sales" : [{ "salesOffering": { "upc" : "01"}, "quantity" : 1 }, { "salesOffering": { "upc" : "01"}, "quantity" : 2 }] }
```

Data:

```
    create or replace table `temp.test` as
SELECT JSON_QUERY_ARRAY(
  JSON '{ "sales" : [{ "salesOffering": { "upc" : "01"}, "quantity" : 1 }, { "salesOffering": { "upc" : "02"}, "quantity" : 1 },{ "salesOffering": { "upc" : "02"}, "quantity" : 1 }, { "salesOffering": { "upc" : "03"}, "quantity" : 1 }, { "salesOffering": { "upc" : "04"}, "quantity" : 1 }, { "salesOffering": { "upc" : "05"}, "quantity" : 1 },{ "salesOffering": { "upc" : "06"}, "quantity" : 1 }, { "salesOffering": { "upc" : "07"}, "quantity" : -1 }] }','$.sales'
  ) AS json_array;
```

I tried using the following query:

```
select array(
    select  json_extract_scalar(jj,"$.salesOffering.upc"), json_extract_scalar(jj,"$.quantity")) from `temp.test` , unnest(json_array) as jj
```

Getting error : ARRAY subquery cannot have more than one column unless using SELECT AS STRUCT to build STRUCT values at [1:8]

How to query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here's the query, hope this meets your requirement

```
with nested_data as (
SELECT json_array FROM (
  SELECT 
  JSON_EXTRACT_ARRAY(
    JSON '{ "sales" : [{ "salesOffering": { "upc" : "01"}, "quantity" : 1 }, { "salesOffering": { "upc" : "02"}, "quantity" : 1 },{ "salesOffering": { "upc" : "02"}, "quantity" : 1 }, { "salesOffering": { "upc" : "03"}, "quantity" : 1 }, { "salesOffering": { "upc" : "04"}, "quantity" : 1 }, { "salesOffering": { "upc" : "05"}, "quantity" : 1 },{ "salesOffering": { "upc" : "06"}, "quantity" : 1 }, { "salesOffering": { "upc" : "07"}, "quantity" : -1 }] }','$.sales'
      ) AS json_array
    )
) SELECT 
    json_extract_scalar(unnest_json,"$.quantity") as quantity,
    json_extract_scalar(unnest_json,"$.salesOffering.upc") as upc,
  FROM nested_data,
  unnest(json_array) as unnest_json
```

Here's the output query:

[image]